# counting number of Tor users

Tags: directory, censorship, consensus

Does the number of directory requests, reported for estimating the number of Tor clients, count the number of requests irrespective of whether or not the consensus was successfully downloaded by the the client? Can someone point out where exactly in the source code the counting is implemented? 
[ticket 18203](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/18203#comment:5)

> I think the reason is that we're counting a response as soon as we consider the request as valid and start sending a response document.

But why not count after the client has successfully received the consensus. What happens if after successfully downloading the consensus, the client cant make a Tor circuit, Does the client try to download a consensus again or just retry with another circuit?